# Почему всегда один и тот же результат в этой простой конструкции IF?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
Помогите новичку, вернее, я вообще из другой отрасли, но пришлось написать с помощью AI простой код для сравнения значений.
К примеру, textValue получает на входе значение "грн", что видно с помощью console.log(textValue);
а тип console.log(typeof(textValue));
string

А в результате на выходе всегда "Unknown Text Value".

код:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".confirmation-block__pay-price");
var elementStyle = getComputedStyle(element, "::after");
var textValue = (elementStyle.content);
var convertedTextValue = "";
  
  console.log(textValue); // "грн"
  
if (textValue == "грн")   
  convertedTextValue = "UAH";
  else if (textValue == "\0024")
  convertedTextValue = "USD";  
  else if (textValue == "\20AC")
  convertedTextValue = "EUR";
  else
  convertedTextValue = "Unknown Text Value";

  console.log(convertedTextValue);
```

Буду признателен за подсказу, т.к. есть срочная задача, а спросить, как выяснилось не у кого

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @andreymal, там проще)

Comment: Покажите что выводит `encodeURIComponent(textValue)`

Comment: Даже если вы удалите кавычки перед сранвнением, посмотрите что у вас будет выводить консоль для этого контента \0024.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что значение лежит вместе с кавычками, что отлично видно по выводу в консоль:

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".confirmation-block__pay-price");
var elementStyle = getComputedStyle(element, "::after");
var textValue = elementStyle.content;

console.log(textValue);
console.log("грн");
console.log('"грн"');
```

```css
.confirmation-block__pay-price::after {
  content: "грн"
}
```

```html
<div class="confirmation-block__pay-price"></div>
```

Comment: т.е. сравнивать нужно с чем-то типа "\"грн\"" ?

Comment: @alecsasha, вроде логично.